# Wordpress: Adding an extra folder name in the url before all posts

Tags: php, wordpress, url

Is there anyway of doing the following?

In my wordpress build I have a homepage [test.com] an index page [news] and single posts [single]

At the moment if I navigate to news and then onto single the url is as follows:
test.com/single

However ideally I want: test.com/news/single

Is there a function/ plugin I can use to add in this extra folder name?

Comment: You will need a category to assign that single post with having name `news`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a Permalinks structure. They can be used to create a structure similar to what you are trying to achieve.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Assign that single post to a category
2. Check if your permalinks are set to **"Post Name"**